# How to move WordPress function code to the bottom of the content

Tags: php, wordpress

I added the following code to my functions.php file in WordPress to add a "Last Updated on ..." date message to every blog post:

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
$u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
$updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
$updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
$custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated">Last updated on '. 
$updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
} 

$custom_content .= $content;
return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

And this adds something like this at the top of the content of a blog post:
https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/1Q0G0D1c3x313E1H0d05/Image%202018-06-19%20at%207.40.11%20AM.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2866569

Is it possible to edit the PHP code so that instead of adding it to the top of the content, it adds it to the bottom of the content? If so, could you please provide me with the code sample?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: You are currently appending $content to the date that you've created for each post. You need to append $content to a placeholder variable then append $custom_content and return the placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
$u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
$updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
$updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
$custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated">Last updated on '. 
$updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
} 

$content .= $custom_content;
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're appending your main content to your $custom_content on the line:

```
$custom_content .= $content;
```

If you switch those 2 variables around and return $content instead you'll append the data, rather than prepending it:

```
$content .= $custom_content;
return $content;
```